# Find the range from pandas column for each month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an pandas dataframe as

```
datetime   value month
2021-03-01  10   March
2021-03-28  15   March
2021-04-02  10   April
2021-04-05  12   April
2021-04-31  20   April
2021-05-10  15   May
2021-05-27  30   May
```

I would like to obtain the Last value from a Month - The first value of the month

The expected result should look like this:

```
Month  Value
March  15-10=5
April  20-10=10
May    30-15=15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use a named [`GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and get [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html)-[`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
g = df.groupby('month')['value']
out = g.last()-g.first()
```

or, using [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
out = df.groupby('month')['value'].apply(lambda g: g.last()-g.first())
```

output:

```
month
April    10
March     5
May      15
Name: value, dtype: int64
```